# Read GZip compressed Data in Stream

Tags: c#, gzip

My aim is to compress a file using gzip an then write the compressed bytes into an Xml section, which means that I need the compressed byte array in my code. All examples for GZip I found just wrote the bytes directly to a file.

So here is my code:

```
public ContainerFile(string[] inputFiles, string Output)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlNode root;

        FileInfo fi;
        FileStream fstream;
        BinaryReader reader;
        GZipStream gstream;



        root = doc.CreateElement("compressedFile");
        doc.AppendChild(root);

        foreach (string f in inputFiles)
        {
            fstream = File.OpenRead(f);
            MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[fstream.Length];
            // Read the file to ensure it is readable.
            int count = fstream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            if (count != buffer.Length)
            {
                fstream.Close();
                //Console.WriteLine("Test Failed: Unable to read data fromfile");
            return;
            }
            fstream.Close();

            gstream = new GZipStream(s, CompressionMode.Compress, true);
            gstream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            gstream.Flush();


            byte[] bytes = new byte[s.Length];

            s.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

            File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\compressed.gz", bytes);

        }
```

for debugging reasons, I just tried to write the data into a file after it was loaded.

So, the length of the input file is ~4k bytes. As the degubber shows me, the length of the "bytes"- array is ~2k. So it looks like the size of the compressed byte array is right, but all values in it are 0.

Can s.o. help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Read` call is trying to read from the *end* of the `MemoryStream` - you haven't "rewound" it. You *could* do that with `s.Position = 0;` - but it would be simpler to just call `MemoryStream.ToArray`.

Note that I would personally try *not* to read from streams assuming that the entire data will be available in one go, as you're doing to start with. You should also use `using` statements for streams to avoid leaking handles if an exception is thrown. However, using `File.ReadAllBytes` would be simpler anyway:

```
byte[] inputData = File.ReadAllBytes();
using (var output = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var compression = new GZipStream(output, CompressionMode.Compress,
                                            true))
    {
        compression.Write(inputData, 0, inputData.Length);
    }
    File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\compressed.gz", output.ToArray());
}
```

It's not clear why you're using a `MemoryStream` in the first place here, given that you're then writing the data out to a file...